# How do I delete a non-empty Workspace and its corresponding Namespace with the Geoserver ( 2.10.2 ) REST API

Tags: geoserver

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/workspaces.html

When I try to send a delete request to `http://mygeoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace`, I get `Namespace for workspace not empty.`, even if I add the parameter `recurse=true` which is supposed to  deletes all layers referenced.

Comment: which version of GeoServer?

Comment: 2.10.2 is the version

Answer (score 1):

We could try following request (for curl):

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace?recurse=true
```

Comment: that is what I did, but with `DELETE` instead of `XDELETE`. What is the difference?